# In Vscode I am facing a problem while creating a react app

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, installation

I have used the command

```
> npx create-react-app my-app

Need to install the following packages:
  create-react-app
Ok to proceed? (y)
 // I apply the command but the result is
Ok to proceed? (y) y

You are running `create-react-app` 4.0.3, which is behind the latest release (5.0.0).

We no longer support global installation of Create React App.

Please remove any global installs with one of the following commands:
- npm uninstall -g create-react-app
- yarn global remove create-react-app

The latest instructions for creating a new app can be found here:
https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `npx clear-npx-cache` to clear cache and then running `npx create-react-app@latest my-app --use-npm` to install latest version

Answer (score 0):

First, check your npm version with command `npm --version` to see if it is because your npm version is too old (mine is 6.14.14).Reinstall `npm` to see if it solves the problem.

If it doesn't, try to uninstall the `create-react-app` as the document suggests, using `npm uninstall -g create-react-app`, and **YOU DON'T NEED TO INSTALL IT**!   `npm` will take care of this for you.

These are the two suggestions I can think of so far.